# How can you use COUNT() in a comparison in a SELECT CASE clause in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions, select-case

Let's say you want do something along the following lines:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE column2 = 4) > 0
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Basically just return 1 when there's one or more rows in the table, 0 otherwise.  There has to be a grammatically correct way to do this.  What might it be?  Thanks!

Comment: For testing existence, RedFilter has the answer. Generally, your query for testing counts is correct as it stands (as long as a valid table name is subbed for `table`.

Comment: If you care about performance, you've accepted the wrong answer. Not sure why you would want to rush, or assume that the first answer must be the best solution.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(ID) >=1 THEN 1 WHEN COUNT (ID) <1 THEN 0 END FROM table WHERE Column2=4
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: StackOverflow really needs to let people go ahead and accept answers as soon as they start coming in, not make them wait 10 minutes.  I'll accept yours in a minute.

Comment: Why count all records when merely checking the existence of any with `EXISTS` will suffice?

Comment: Well, it was just an example of how it might be used.  Thanks though, man; I didn't realize that keyword existed.  Sorry if I focused on the example a little too much.

Comment: What was wrong with the OP's own query which is far less convoluted?

Comment: @Panzercrisis why, so you can accept a bad answer before people can correct it and show you the right way to do what you've asked to do?

Comment: @JKarthik Sorry, but this answer is the wrong idea. An expensive count is not necessary here, never mind trying to coerce the optimizer into performing it TWICE!

Comment: Guys, I sincerely want to accept both answers, and I might blame myself for over-emphasizing the example.  But the real question that's in the title is a more general notion than checking existence.  I agree that the situation got a little awkward on which answer to choose, but I had to emphasize what reflected the main question over the answer that was closer to what I've actually used in my own code.  It's just fair.  I have up-voted all three answers though, and due to the quality of RedFilter's answer, he's received quite a bit of reputation pretty quickly from it anyway.

Comment: Panzercrisis Agree with the rest (and the -8 votes). My answer isn't performance-tuned. Aaron Thanks for pointing it out, I agree with your point. All, Choice of accepting an answer lies with the OP. The votes, comments everything helps the OP make an informed decision. But whatever suits, suits. And I think my response was posted second , after RedFilter posted.

My motiviation was to show that, you can move down the CASE comparison alongside COUNT() itself.

Answer (score 33):

Question: *return 1 when there's one or more rows in the table, 0 otherwise*:

In this case, there is no need for `COUNT`. Instead, use `EXISTS`, which rather than counting all records will return as soon as **any** is found, which performs much better:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE column2 = 4)    
        THEN 1  
    ELSE 0 
END
```

Comment: does it apply to complex query?

Comment: @SteveLam You can use any valid `SELECT` query within the `EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Mahmoud Gammal posted an answer with an interesting approach. Unfortunately the answer was deleted due to the fact that it returned the count of records instead of just `1`. This can be fixed using [the `sign` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420.aspx), leading to this more compact solution:

```
SELECT sign(count(*)) FROM table WHERE column2 = 4
```

I posted this because I find it an interesting approach. In production I'd usually end up with something close to RedFilter's answer.

Comment: ISNULL is redundant on COUNT() which never returns NULL.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I should have realized that; thanks for the great tip! I've edited my answer.